# How to extract parameter value from redirect url and put it to another one?

Tags: jmeter, load

I ran into a problem in JMeter.

I have URL and into body there is GET [http://test.com/registration?test={value}](http://test.com/registration?test=%7Bvalue%7D) and I need to extract value of test parameter and put this value to the next url to another parameter.

I used Regular Expression Extractor but all I can do is pull out the whole URL but not specific value from the URL.

By way of example:

1. http://test.com/browse where we have code 303 and in the body

`<a href="http://test.com/registration?test={value}">See Other</a>.`

2. I need to extract value from [http://test.com/registration?test={value}](http://test.com/registration?test=%7Bvalue%7D) and put this value to the another URL

If you have any thoughts on this please help. Thanks in advance!

I used Regular Expression Extractor but all I can do is pull out the whole URL but not specific value from the URL.

Probably there are any other ways to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this [regular expression](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html):

```
test=(.+?)"
```

[image]

Full configuration just in case:

[image]

You will be able to refer extracted value as `${value}` where required.

You might find [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) easier to use, in this case you just need to provide "left" and "right" boundaries and it will extract everything in-between:

[image]

More information: [The Boundary Extractor vs. the Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-boundary-extractor)

Comment: Thank you Dmitry for your help! One more question to clarify please. 

My example:
- I have registration ULR: http://test.com/registration where I enter mail, password, name and click Sign Up
- By clicking on Sign Up button, to this URL added parameter test=[with dynamic value]  http://test.com/registration?test={value} and send POST request with data

How to extract this value and pass to this parameter every load test because this value each time different

Thank you!